# Convert a user's 24h input to 12h

Tags: c#, datetime

So for some reason this comes up with an error message saying that 'no overload for method'ParseExact' takes 1 argument'. Does anyone know what I've done wrong?

```
 static void runTimeConverter()
{   
 double arrivalTime;
 arrivalTime = getArrivalTime();
 string time = DateTime.ParseExact(arrivalTime).ToString("HH:mm tt");
 Console.WriteLine("Equals " + time);
}

 static double getArrivalTime()

    {
        Console.WriteLine
            ("Enter time in 24 hour format to convert to 12hour");
        string timeSelected = Console.ReadLine();
        int timeInput = int.Parse(timeSelected);
        return timeInput;
    }
```

Comment: The problem is you're only giving it one argument. Check out the reference material: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx

Comment: I'd wager a guess that the problem is that no overload for the method exists that takes one argument. :)

Comment: The error message is pretty explicit, read [the doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or look at the intellisense.

Comment: What are you trying to do, you are trying to parse a double value, by calling `ToString` like it is a date, and then using `DateTime.ParseExact` which should return a `DateTime` object , but you are storing it in a string. **It is a lot more than just one missing parameter** to `DateTime.ParseExact`

Answer (score 5):

> So for some reason this comes up with an error message saying that 'no overload for 
>   method'ParseExact' takes 1 argument'. Does anyone know what I've done
>   wrong?

Yes. YOu can not read or refuse to process the error message the compiler shows you - that is VERY exact in what is wrong.

YOur code:

> DateTime.ParseExact(arrivalTime)

That is one argument. The compiler says it is wrong.

If you check the documentation:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

it shows he method as:

```
public static DateTime ParseExact(
    string s,
    string format,
    IFormatProvider provider
)
```

THat is 3 arguments. You only give one. DOes not get more obvious. Fix your code.

Comment: There are actually currently three overloads for this method, and you show only one. Your answer might be improved with more accuracy about overloading, which is coincidentally what the actual error says.

Comment: Whats a good IFormatProvider to use? most of the ones i've had a look at like the CultureInfo.CurrentCulture gets an error that it does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Your therad has a current ui culture - likely you want to use that. Or a specific one.

Comment: string time = DateTime.ParseExact(arrivalTime, "hhmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("HH:mm");
why doesn't CultureInfo.InvariantCulture exist in the current context? do i have to declare them first, thought the IFormatProvider were registered with visual studio.

Comment: That would be another question, would it not?

Answer (score 0):

Because `ParseExact` expects the exact format to parse the given string as date, which you aren't providing.