# Convert 24h to 12h in c# (IFormatProvider trouble)

Tags: c#

So the following code comes up with the Name 'CultureInfo' does not exist in the current context, I've tried other IFormatProviders but they're not registering in Visual Studio. What am I doing wrong?

```
   static void runTimeConverter()
 {   
  double arrivalTime;
  arrivalTime = getArrivalTime();  
  string time = DateTime.ParseExact(arrivalTime, "HHmm", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
   .ToString("hh:mm tt");
  Console.WriteLine("Equals " + time);
 }

static double getArrivalTime()

   {
    Console.WriteLine
        ("Enter time in 24 hour format to convert to 12hour");
    string timeSelected = Console.ReadLine();
    int timeInput = int.Parse(timeSelected);
    return timeInput;
}
```

Comment: Add the appropriate Using, which is `System.Globalization;`. We linked you the doc in your previous question, read it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert a user's 24h input to 12h](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23113513/convert-a-users-24h-input-to-12h)

Comment: Now its saying that the best overload match has invalid arguments. I'm assuming its the arrivalTime part. If it is how do I convert the user's input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure this is added to the top of the file:

```
using System.Globalization;
```

Comment: Now its saying that the best overload match has invalid arguments. I'm assuming its the arrivalTime part. If it is how do I convert the user's input?

Comment: You've converting the users input to a double and then trying to parse that. Look at the method signature: DateTime.ParseExact(string, string, IFormatInfo). A string is expected. Just use the raw string value entered by the user from the console.

Comment: I'm sting having trouble using a raw string value entered by the user. I made the following alterations.
string arrivalTime;
arrivalTime = getArrivalTime(); //for the main alteration

 static string getArrivalTime()
        {
            Console.WriteLine
                ("What time would you like to arrive at your destination in 24hour format?");

            string timeSelected = Console.ReadLine();
            return timeSelected;

        }

Comment: What are you entering exactly, and what is the console output/compiler error?

Comment: Never mind had a typo error.. Thanks very much for your help.